# locale-gen command in centos6

Tags: locale, centos, docker

In my bare centos6.5 system, which is a `docker` container, `en_US.utf-8` locale is missing:

```
bash-4.1# locale -a
C
POSIX
```

Normally in Ubuntu there is command `locale-gen` to do this:

```
# locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
# echo 'LANG="en_US.UTF-8"' > /etc/default/locale
```

How can I do this in centos 6.5?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`locale-gen` is not present in `Centos/Fedora`.

You must use `localedef`:

```
localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
```

From `man localedef`:

```
NAME
       localedef - define locale environment

SYNOPSIS
       localedef [-c][-f charmap][-i sourcefile][-u code_set_name] name

DESCRIPTION
       The localedef utility shall convert source definitions for locale cate‐
       gories into a format usable by the functions and utilities whose opera‐
       tional behavior is determined by the setting of the locale  environment
       variables    defined    in    the    Base    Definitions    volume   of
       IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Chapter 7, Locale. It  is  implementation-defined
       whether users have the capability to create new locales, in addition to
       those  supplied  by  the  implementation.  If  the  symbolic   constant
       POSIX2_LOCALEDEF  is  defined,  the system supports the creation of new
       locales.    On   XSI-conformant   systems,   the   symbolic    constant
       POSIX2_LOCALEDEF shall be defined.
```

Comment: thank, `yum whatprovides */localedef` reports for `glibc-common` package, while `/usr/bin/localedef` doesn't exist. strange, because of docker ?

Comment: @larrycai: I'm not sure, haven't seen this problem before. What result `ldd /usr/bin/localedef`.

Comment: the file doesn't exist, only `locale` command. If u know docker, you can run `docker run -i -t centos bash` to check as well.

Comment: Thanks sir ~ I was getting quite annoyed by the odd chars :)

Comment: It didn't work for me in ubi8 out of the box. To make it work you have to install `glibc-locale-source` package. Otherwise localedef will complain: `[error] character map file UTF-8 not found: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 8):

I provided extra information based on answer @Gnouc (`localedef` shall be used in centos)

The `centos docker` is a special image which provides minimal packages, see script https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh

```
rm -rf "$target"/usr/{{lib,share}/locale,{lib,lib64}/gconv,bin/localedef,sbin/build-locale-archive}
```

Inside command `localedef` is removed, `glibc-common` package which include this shall be reinstalled

```
yum reinstall glibc-common
```

surely the size will be increased

Comment: `yum reinstall glibc-common` made localedef available for me on Amazon Linux `2.17-196.172.amzn1` Docker container: https://hub.docker.com/r/ambakshi/amazon-linux/ and allowed me to get elixir installed.